# Does the app restart after it crashes when in background - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-process

I am getting the location updates in background (on `BroadcastReceiver`) using **Google API**'s `FusedLocationProvider`. When the **app is in background**, if a crash occurs(let's say a `NullPointerException`) and the user choses one of the two options displayed(***Open the app again*** or ***close the app*** or ***send feedback***).

Will the app restart itself?

If it doesn't start, is it possible to start the background location updates manually without opening the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, I found that the app does restart or recover itself after it crashes regardless of clicking any of the three options mentioned in the question.